# Switch "when" cannot see constants?

Tags: apex, switch

I am trying to use a switch statement with constants but it doesn't appear that the switch statement can see the constants.

At the top of the class I have:
`private final String A_B_C = 'a b c';`

Then later in the class I am attempting:

```
switch on OpportunityTriggerHelper.recordTypes.get(opp.RecordTypeId).getDeveloperName() {
        when A_B_C {
            // do something
        }
}
```

What I get is `variable doesn't exist A_B_C`.

I know for a fact that that variable is visible because there's no problem using it in an if statement.

Is this a bug or am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The when clause can accept the following three types of values

**A)** when literal {} (a when block can have multiple, comma-separated literal clauses)

**B)** when SObjectType identifier {}

**C)** When enum_value {}

Anything apat from this will give a compiletime error.

In your case,

`private final String A_B_C = 'a b c';` is a variable and not a literal and hence it gives you an error.

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_switch.htm